# How to fix 'Error(9,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values' in a function?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, procedure

I'm trying to get a total commission for each Sale staff and store it to a function to put it in a procedure, when I put a working select statement (three tables involved), I got `Error(9,20): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values`. I think because datatype only returns number in this function, but the table contains other varchar datatypes that cause this problem.

I tried to remove some columns that are varchar2 datatype but the result is not correct.

Below is my fictional code:

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_total_commission return number 
IS
  v_total_commission;
--
begin
      select
      sale_id, sale_acct,sale_name, sum(commission) as total_commission      
      into v_total from invoice_tbl invoice join commission_tbl commission
      on invoice.id = commission.id join sale_tbl sale on sale.id = commssion.id
      where invoice.refnr is null;
  return to_char(v_total, 'FM99999.00');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('err: ' ||SQLERRM);  

end get_total_commission;
```

It will be a function that will show the total amount of commission that earns by each Sale staff.

Comment: Yes, i knew this is one of the problem and I don&#39;t know how to return more than one data type as am no expert of it...

Comment: Only the total amount of commssion for each Sale earn...Should I remove columns that contains varchar to match with the return data type?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use local variable to which all your four columns in the SELECT list return to. And because of conversion to character type, need to return a string type value instead of numeric for the function.

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total_commission RETURN varchar2 IS
  v_total_commission commission_tbl.commission%type;
  v_sale_id          sale_tbl.sale_id%type;
  v_sale_acct        sale_tbl.sale_acct%type;
  v_sale_name        sale_tbl.sale_name%type;
BEGIN
  select sale_id, sale_acct, sale_name, sum(commission) as total_commission
    into v_sale_id, v_sale_acct, v_sale_name, v_total
    from invoice_tbl invoice
    join commission_tbl commission
      on invoice.id = commission.id
    join sale_tbl sale
      on sale.id = commssion.id
   where invoice.refnr is null;
  return to_char(v_total, 'FM99999.00');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('err: ' || SQLERRM);

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

> the total amount of commission that earns by each Sale staff

Sounds like returning one number shorn of identifying characteristics is not the solution you need. You need a result set. Personally, this seems better fitted to a view than a function but if you want to wrap the query in a function this is how to do it:

```
-- obviously correct these data types to fit your actual needs
create or replace type commission_t as object(
    sale_id varchar2(30)
    , acct_id varchar2(30)
    , sale_name varchar2(48)
    , total_commission_number
);
/

create or replace type commission_nt as table of commission_t; 
/

create or replace FUNCTION get_total_commission return commission_nt
IS
    return_value commission_nt;
begin
      select commission_t(
                   sale_id, sale_acct,sale_name, sum(commission) )   
      bulk collect into return_type
      from invoice_tbl invoice 
           join commission_tbl commission on invoice.id = commission.id 
          join sale_tbl sale on sale.id = commssion.id
      where invoice.refnr is null
      group by sale_id, sale_acct,sale_name
      ;

     return return_value;  

end get_total_commission;
```

And query it like this:

```
select * from table (get_total_commission);
```

There are various rough edges with this. For instance it won't work well if your result set is huge (which obviously depends, but say more than 5000-10000 rows).

---

If you really just want the total commission for a single sale then you need to restrict the query by SALE_ID - and pass it as a parameter:

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_total_commission 
    (p_sale_id in sale.id%type)
    return number 
IS
  v_total_commission number;
--
begin

      select
      sum(commission) as total_commission      
      into v_total_commission 
      from invoice_tbl invoice 
           join commission_tbl commission on invoice.id = commission.id 
           join sale_tbl sale on sale.id = commssion.id
      where sale.id = p_sale_id
      and invoice.refnr is null;

      return v_total_commission ;

end get_total_commission;
```